# How can i write a loading page with play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I would like to implement a page that be displayed to the user whilst a system command is run. As soon as the command completes the user should be routed to another page.

What are some strategies to implement this?

*(A solution without javascript would be ideal)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can definitely be done. You want to look at [Asynchronous programming with HTTP](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous) in the documentation, it explains how to do this in a non-blocking way. You will need a little bit of javascript for the redirecting part though.

And I don't know what you mean with "system command" but you probably want to [create a job](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jobs#tasks) for it, so you can trigger it with a request. You can then [poll it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling) until it's finished and then redirect the user. But really the documentation does  an infinitely better job at explaining it then I'm doing now.

Here's an example of a controller action where I assume your system command returns some kind of String output for the user. When the Job is completed it will sent a response to the user, thus triggering the success handler in the javascript example.

```
public static void executeSystemCommand(String input) {
    Promise<String> outputPromise = new SystemCommandJob(input).now();
    String output = await(outputPromise);
    renderText(output);
}
```

Basically if you're using jQuery's `$.ajax` you can use the *complete* event to poll the data (just do the request again if it didn't succeed within the timeout time) and use the *success/done event* to redirect the user when the application responds to indicate that the "system command" is done running.

Example of a function you could use:

```
function poll(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/systemcommand", 
        success: function(data){
            // redirect to next page here
            document.location.href = '/output'
        }, 
        complete: poll, 
        timeout: 20000  
    });
};
```

There is also [a great example on long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) in javascript on StackOverflow.